# Check Iterated row on a table if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this kind of structure in my `JSP`

```
<c:forEach var="test" value="${test}">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea class="no-resize" id="comments"></textarea></td>
        <td><select class="select"> ... </select> </td>
        <td><textarea class="no-resize" id="reason"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="no-resize" id="description"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</c:forEach>
```

and a save button:

```
<button class="btn " type="submit" form="controller" name="save" value="save" id="save" onclick="return onSave()">Save</button>
```

Each row is basicaly is empty and what I want to do is, when the save button is clicked only submit when:

1. The changed row must fill all the fields
2. Or all fields will remain empty

using jQuery if possible.

What i tried so far is:

```
         var isFilled = true;
         $(".no-resize[id='comments']").each(function(){
             $(this).change(function(){
                if(!$(this).val() == ''){
                    setTextBox(false);
                }else{
                    setTextBox(true);
                }
             });
         });
         function setTextBox(isEmpty)
         {
             isFilled = isEmpty;
         }

         function onSave()
         {
             return isFilled; 
         };
```

The code above checks if the `textarea` with the `id comments` changed and if its empty it will set the `isFilled` to `false` so the submission will fail. The problem of the code I have done is when I changed two `textarea` with the `id of comments` it will only check the last changed `textarea`.

Any idea of how to work this out?

Comment: Having multiple elements on the page with the same `id` is not valid HTML.

Comment: `.no-resize[id='comments']` this will check only one textbox with id `comments`. use different `id's` for different elements.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Alright I will remove the id.

Comment: @Unknown i can only make a different `id` with jstl (id = "comments-${var}" something like this) i don't know how can i get the idea to jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//this is a flag which will be set to false if an invalid row is found
var valid = true;
//iterate through each row of the table, it is because we need to validate the textarea's in each row
$('tr').each(function(){
    //all textarea's in the row
    var els =  $(this).find('textarea');

    //we uses filter to find the textarea's where the length of the textarea is 0
    var len = els.filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).value()).length == 0;
    });
    //if the textarea's length is neither 0 or not equals to the total length then it is not valie
    if(len > 0 && len != els.length){
        valid = false;
        return false;
    }
});

if(!valid){
    //there are incomplete records
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit your code? I'm actually new to jQuery i don't know how would i integrate your code to mine.